# Codeigniter can't load model

Tags: php, codeigniter

controllers/verify_login.php page

```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Verify_login extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('adminl_model') ;
 }

 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
     $this->load->view('admin/index');
   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
     redirect('about', 'refresh');
   }

 }

 function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');

   //query the database

   $result = $this->Admin_Model->login($username, $password);

   if($result)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'id' => $row->id,
         'username' => $row->username
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }
 }
}
```

models/adminl_model.php  page

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class Adminl_Model extends CI_Model
{
     function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
 function login($username, $password)
 {
   $this -> db -> select('id, username, password','type');
   $this -> db -> from('users');
   $this -> db -> where('nick', $username);
   $this -> db -> where('type', 'admin');
   $this -> db -> where('pass', MD5($password));
   $this -> db -> limit(1);

   $query = $this -> db -> get();

   if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
   {
     return $query->result();
   }
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
 }
```

}

Gives error. How can I fix that ? I am working on c9.io. and stackoverflow saying that is so codely. I understood my problem that is ridiculous.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: $this->load->model('adminl_model') or die("error"); so just error text

Comment: and php gives ;
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Verify_login::$Admin_Model

Filename: controllers/verify_login.php

Line Number: 40

Comment: not an answer to the question, but if you have "limit(1)" on the query "$query -> num_rows() == 1" is not needed.

Comment: pls provide verify_login controller code

Comment: still got same error. i remove or die part. that is what php gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chunk of code :

```
$result = $this->Admin_Model->login($username, $password);
```

Must be:

```
$result = $this->adminl_model->login($username, $password);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$this->admin_model->login($username, $password);` instead of `$this->Admin_Model->login($username, $password);`

Once loaded, you will access your model functions using an object with the same name as your class:

here you have loaded the model as `$this->load->model('adminl_model') ;`, so u can use adminl_model instead of Admin_Model

Comment: i did it and i said what php says and i added codes of verify_login

Comment: @Nurullah Macun , modified my answer